# Wrong model input when training autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a signal with **1024** values. When I print it in the console I get this output:

```
[-13.2172165 -13.0935545 -13.149217  ...  -1.8910782  -1.5482559 -1.6714929]
```

I've been using a very basic autoencoder code from Keras website which looks like this:

```
encoding_dim = 32
input_signal = Input(shape=(1024,))
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_signal)
decoded = Dense(1024, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

autoencoder = Model(input_signal, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

autoencoder.fit(my_signal, epochs=50, shuffle=True)
```

However, I get this and I don't understand how/why (despite reading intensively the documentation):

`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (1024,) but got array with shape (1,)`

I've been trying to change the shape input in `1024,1` but then it told me that it expects a 3 dimension input but **(here's the weird interpretation)**: my input is an array with shape (1024,1) even though I didn't change the input at all.

**My scenario:** I have 2034 arrays (each one with 1024 elements) that I want to fit into my model. For now, I'm trying to make my autoencoder work only with 1 such array. I understand that I need to set the batch size with the amount of my arrays (2034 in this case).

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried something like `X_train.reshape((-1, 1024, 1))`?

Comment: What is `my_signal.shape`? `(1024,)`?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Yes, `my_signal.shape = (1024,4)`. @BrianJoseph for some reason I get `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: I don't have time to write out a full answer, but here's some tips: If you want to run it on a single sequence, make sure that sequence is in an array of its own, so it has a batch size of 1 (i.e. the shape should be `(1, 1024, ...)`). The shape you give the `Input` layer should be the same shape as each sequence in a batch; it looks like that should be `(1024, 4)`. You're going to have to flatten the input before passing it to the dense layers, and then reshape it back to `(1024, 4)` afterwards. Because your values are not 0-1, you should use `'mse'` instead of `'binary_crossentropy'`.

Comment: Also if you don't have a specific reason to use a specific optimizer, I'd say you should always default to Adam.

Comment: I don't know why I said (1024,4) but it is (1024,).... sorry for the miscommunication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find out my answer: I had to make sure my array is placed in another array (like a 1-D array) like this:
`[[-13.2172165 -13.0935545 -13.149217  ...  -1.8910782  -1.5482559 -1.6714929]]`

I could do it by using:
`x_train.reshape((1,1024))`.